How to check NPU and if possible disable it? (battery savings purpose)
I have read that recent cpus have NPU (neural processing units) too and i would like to disable this feature if possible because i suspect it is the root cause draining my battery faster than windows...
Any ideas?
Thx

No, it can't be disabled and there's no reason to. It isn't the root cause of anything. And if you have hybrid graphics there's your answer: Windows GPU drivers have always been "better" at toggling iGPU/dGPU system-wide and particularly in a per app basis, and that was already the situation long before NPUs have been dreamed of.


The NPU is power gated by default, i.e. its power consumption is zero if you're not using it.
You cannot disable it, but you may choose not to use it.
Battery drain in Linux could be higher and in many cases it's higher because


Laptops firmware is often not optimized for Linux
Hardware drivers in Linux are often not well-optimized as in Windows, the most important are of course for the GPU.
Some hardware interfaces that exist in hardware often do not work properly in Linux, not limited to hardware video decoding/encoding acceleration, switching between the internal and discrete GPUs, power gating of the discrete GPU.

There are some utilities that may help you find the root cause:

powertop
turbostat
nvtop

Under Windows that's HWiNFO64.
